# VS Code - intellisense for Angular types

Tags: angular

Using latest Angular 9 (clean repo, clean VSCode) and F12 (aka "Go to definition") functionality is no longer working as VSCode returns "No definition found ...".

What I find strange is that **all other** libraries are working just fine and when I hover over the Angular Type I do actually see proper content.

Is this known issue or is there any way to solve this? I guess I don't understand why other 3rd party packages work fine, but Angular doesn't.

Comment: have you restarted the vs code?

Comment: sure, I installed everything cleanly just to test this..

Comment: you have installed `@angular/language-service` in your `devDependencies`?

Comment: If you are runing angular 9, your language-service should be `"@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed either by Angular as it started working somewhere around Angular `9.0.7` or by some update in VS Code. I have't made any changes to my repo code. It was probably some a bad coincidence of how my angular project was setup and some minor issue somewhere else.